# use TLS 1.2 to connect securely to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2008-r2, tls1.2, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to connect to a RabbitMQ server using TLS1.2 but I can't seem to do it.  I have verified that my username and password are working as I can connect to the RabbitMQ web client.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace DigitalFulfillmentRabbitMQ
{
    public class RabbitMQService
    {
        public IConnection GetRabbitMqConnection()
        {
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();


           // ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
            // connectionFactory.Ssl.CertificateValidationCallback = CheckValidationResult();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 
            connectionFactory.HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQServer"].ToString();
            connectionFactory.VirtualHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQVHOST"].ToString();
            connectionFactory.Port = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQPort"].ToString());
            connectionFactory.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQAccountUserName"].ToString();
            connectionFactory.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQAccountPassword"].ToString();
           // connectionFactory.Ssl.ServerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            connectionFactory.Ssl.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQServer"].ToString();
            connectionFactory.Ssl.CertPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQSSLCertPath"].ToString();
           // connectionFactory.Ssl.CertPassphrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQSSLCertPassphrase"].ToString();
            connectionFactory.Ssl.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQSSLIsEnabled"].ToString());
            connectionFactory.Ssl.Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;



            return connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

The certificate is a .pem certificate I have put on the client. I'm using port 8071. The certificate path is of format "D:\RabbitMQ_DF_SIT_Server_certificate\ca_certificate.pem". I'm using the RabbitMQ client from NuGet 5.1.0

I doubt I need Certificate Validation Callback Method because from what I understand its one way connection. This application will only consume & not publish at all. What am I missing? The certificate is sitting on the client server but not installed per se.

It throws an error :

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Comment: What version of Erlang are you using? You probably have to enable additional cipher suites [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#cipher-suites). NOTE: the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think what we are going to have to do is procure a new Windows 2016 server.

Comment: UPDATE: After deploying to Windows 2016 server I had no problems. Previous attempts was with Windows 08R2. Others reported the same issue even with Windows 2012.

Comment: That's interesting information, thanks for following up.

Comment: Note  the RabbitMQ server I was trying to connect to at the time was on some sort of Linux box. My guess is since the server where my application was trying to pull messages from was old windows the old windows -> Linux probably contributed to the problem of not being able to negotiate a common cipher.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use TLS with RabbitMQ one has to enable this via the RabbitMQ config located in Windows at `%APPDATA%/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq.conf` file.

Depending on the Erlang version being used, the config can be the classic format / ini style. For more details, please refer to https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

With the newer ini style configuration format, the config should look like this

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.verify               = verify_none
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
ssl_options.cacertfile           = <location to cacertfile.crt>
ssl_options.certfile             = <location to certfile.crt>
ssl_options.keyfile              = <location to private.key>
```

All of the above can be automated and verified via a script that I wrote for this
https://gist.github.com/skewl84/a72321379a65c4c5cfd447f8806b5188

The script above does

- Check if OpenSSL is installed else download to generate Self-Signed certificate if neccessary
- Modify RabbbitMQ config to enable TLS
- Use OpenSSL to Test TLS after it has been enabled on the RabbitMQ

Comment: good to know. I was only involved getting tls1.2 to work on the consumer side.